# How can I read a OneDrive directory with Apache Camel?

Tags: sharepoint, apache-camel, onedrive

I want to be able to automate reading files from a one-drive link, or from SharePoint online.

I had seen a reference to using Camel-CMIS 
[Using Apache Camel CMIS with Sharepoint 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29621858/using-apache-camel-cmis-with-sharepoint-2013) which seemed to be what I wanted, but according to [CMIS support for Sharepoint and OneDrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991075/cmis-support-for-sharepoint-and-onedrive), this applies only to On-Prem SharePoint and I need to access online OneDrive/SharePoint as none of the sites I need to access are on-prem.

Is there another component or approach that can to do this in Camel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems as there is no camel component (yet) for OneDrive.

That being said, there are a few java clients, that make integrating OneDrive in java easier. Here are some examples:
https://github.com/nuxeo/onedrive-java-client
https://github.com/isac322/OneDrive-SDK-java

The best thing to do would be writing the Camel Component based one of those clients and adding it to the official camel repository.
Alternatively, you could use camel routes to do the whole process and then write plain java code where the OneDrive integration comes in.
I have done the same for other services, that only have a java client, but no camel integration.
The advantage is, that you still get all the awesome stuff, that camel brings (robust runnable, error handling, routing etc.)

For example:

```
from("direct:toOneDrive")
  .process(exchange -> {
    // Do the OneDrive stuff
  })
.to("direct:afterOneDrive");
```